# Problem with dataframe using beautiful soup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I create a dataframe using beautiful soup scraping the data. However, there have 2 problems.

1. Why does the for loop run 2 times?
2. How to remove the brackets on the data frame?

import urllib.request as req

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BF-B/profile?p=BF-B"

root = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(root.text, 'html.parser')

records = []

for result in soup:
name = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'D(ib) Fz(18px)'})
website = soup.find_all('a')[44]
sector = soup.find_all('span')[35]
industry = soup.find_all('span')[37]
records.append((name, website, sector, industry))

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['name', 'website', 'sector', 'industry'])
df.head()
```

And the result like this:

[DataFrame Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NuyV.png)

Comment: Have you done any debugging for the loop issue? What are the brackets for? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get information about the company, you don't have to loop over the `soup`, just extract necessary information directly. To get rid of `[..]` brackets, use `.text` property:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BF-B/profile?p=BF-B'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []

all_data.append({
    'Name': soup.h1.text,
    'Website': soup.select_one('.asset-profile-container a[href^="http"]')['href'],
    'Sector': soup.select_one('span:contains("Sector(s)") + span').text,
    'Industry': soup.select_one('span:contains("Industry") + span').text
})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                              Name                      Website              Sector                           Industry
0  Brown-Forman Corporation (BF-B)  http://www.brown-forman.com  Consumer Defensive  Beverages—Wineries & Distilleries
```